# Is there a portal dedicated to HTML5 games?

Tags: html5, game-industry, web, online

*Just to get something straight; by "portal", I mean a website that frequently publishes a certain type of games, has a blog, some articles, maybe some tutorials and so on. All of these things are not required (except the game publishing part, of course), for example, I consider [Miniclip](http://www.miniclip.com/games/en/) to be a flash game portal. The reason for defining this term is because I'm not sure if other people use it in this context.*

I recently (less than a year ago) got into HTML5 game development, nothing serious, just my own small projects that I didn't really show to a lot of people, and that certainly didn't end up somewhere on the web (although, I am planning to make a website for my next game). I am interested in the existence of an online portal where indie devs (or non-indie ones, doesn't really matter that much) can publish their own games, sort of like "by devs for devs", also a place where you can find some simple tutorials on basic HTML5 game development and so on... I doubt something like this exists for several reasons:

1. You can't really commercialize an HTML5 game without a strong server-side and microtransactions
2. The code can be easily copied
3. HTML5 is simply new, and things need time to get their own portals somewhere...

If a thing like this does not exist, I think I might get into making one some day...

Comment: Does http://html5games.com/ not count?

Comment: This is not a very constructive question. It only has a yes/no answer, and the answer is 'yes.' The asker could've found that out by searching either 'html5 games' or 'html5 game portal' - a portal shows up in the first result page for both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some sites you can check out:

- http://html5games.com/
- http://www.html5games.net/
- http://www.canvasdemos.com/
- http://www.html5gamers.com/
- http://www.gameshtml5.net/
- http://tophtml5games.com/
- http://html5gamer.net/
- http://html5arcade.com

Answer (score 3):

[image]
http://www.scirra.com/arcade

Although it only accepts HTML5 games made in Construct 2.  Also other links you requested:

**Blog:**
http://www.scirra.com/blog

**Tutorials:** http://www.scirra.com/tutorials